# how to get most frequent value when grouped by ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to find most occuring value when grouped by ID

EDIT : I grouped the names with ID, using this ID, it has a person name associated with it, each name has multiple cities, I need to pull a unique name with the most frequent city. Min and Max functions do not work I think.

I hope below table example is helpful.

```
Col_1  Col_2  
1        A       
1        B       
1        A       
2        D 
2        D
2        C
```

I want result as

```
Col_1  Col_2  
1        A       
2        D
```

Comment: _when grouped by ID_ So which column that you actually show us is the ID column in question

Comment: @nacho that doesn't show the most common value in each group, it shows the most common overall.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Sorry, it is AWS Athena.

Comment: EDIT : I grouped the names with ID, using this each name has multiple cities, I need to pull a unique name with the most frequent city. Min and Max functions do not work I think.